# How to scroll to particular element using CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

This is the dummy code. My requirement is when I click on last `li` element then one `hidden div` inside it will be displayed.But I need to `scroll` down to it to see it.
So when I click on `li` with `id=hello` then window should automatically scroll down to that div?

First preference using CSS then JS and no jQuery.

```js
var ele=document.getElementById('hello');


ele.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    document.getElementById("hidden-div").style.display="block";
},false);
```

```css
.fixed-height-div{
 height:120px;
 overflow-y:scroll;
}

.fixed-height-div > li{
    background-color:lightblue;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed-height-div">
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
  <li>D</li>
  <li>E</li>
  <li>F</li>
  <li>G</li>
  <li id="hello">H
      <div id="hidden-div" style="display:none;">
          This should be displayed after click<br><br>
          And the scroll should come to this screen.
       </div>
    </li>
```

Comment: Do you need it to be animated?

Comment: Anything.Just need to scroll to that div automatically.

Comment: Well, then the first thing I would try is putting a simple anchor element inside your `hello` `li` and setting it's  `href` attribute to `#myHiddenDivsId`. It requires no JS.

Comment: Whether there is any solution using CSS?

Comment: I don't think you can scroll with CSS, as there is no css property that handles the DOM elements scroll. I at least never came across of it.

Comment: Adding animation to that div or li?\

Comment: Yeah, but what kind of animation? You could animate the div to some other position, but you can't _scroll_ the page using CSS. Or did I not understand your last question?

Comment: Doubt cleared thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just after you show/expand your hidden div, call the `scrollIntoView` function of the `li` element.

This requires no jQuery.

```
function showIt(elementId) {
    var el = document.getElementById(elementId);
    el.scrollIntoView(true);
}
```

For more refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollIntoView

Comment: Can u provide solution using CSS? +1 for this JS solution

Comment: @ShoaibChikate I doubt you can scroll a div using css. Although you can give effects using css while the div scrolls. But you cannot actually set a scroll value using css.

Answer (score 1):

You can use anchor redirecting `window.location = currentlocation + "#" + id`, or you can use jquery lib - [scrollTo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/)

edit:
I read it cannnot be jQuery. Try this:

```
ele.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    document.getElementById("hidden-div").style.display="block";
    window.location.href = window.location.href + "#hidden-div";
},false);
```

Comment: Can u provide solution using CSS? +1 for this JS solution.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no solution using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

```
var ele=document.getElementById('hello');
ele.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    document.getElementById("hidden-div").style.display="block";
    var top = this.offsetTop;
    this.parentNode.scrollTop += top; //Container div scroll
    document.body.scrollTop += top; //Body scroll
},false);
```